# Java create a transparent color

Tags: java, colors

I'm using a graphics library (jPCT) and for the background of the FrameBuffer I would like it to be transparent so that I can paste my graphics on top of another view.

In a `onDrawFrame` method I have:

```
fb.clear(back);
```

Where I've tried:

```
private RGBColor back = new RGBColor(0,0,0,0);
```

However this just makes the background completely black; how can I get transparent?

Thanks.

Comment: Note - this class comes from jPCT: http://www.jpct.net/doc/com/threed/jpct/RGBColor.html and it extends Java's color class

Comment: What did you expect to happen when choosing RGBA = (0,0,0,0)? It will appear black unless you composite it over something else.